# How can I register Racket engine in knit and rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, racket, knitr

I installed Racket (https://racket-lang.org/) on windows 10 and added the Racket folder into the Enviroment Variables "Path". I tried to use Racket code in Rmarkdown and I have to register Racket engine in knit:

```
knitr::knit_engines$set(Racket = function(options) {
  code <- paste(options$code, collapse = '\n')
  out  <- system2(
    'Racket', shQuote(code), stdout = TRUE
  )
  knitr::engine_output(options, code, out)
})
```

Then I wrote Racket code in Rmarkdown:

````
```{Racket, engine.path='C:/Racket/Racket', stdout=TRUE}
#lang sicp
(define (inc x) (+ x 1))
(define (dec x) (- x 1))
(inc 6)
```
````

But it failed and showed :

```
Warning in system2("Racket", shQuote(code), stdout = TRUE) : 
running command '"Racket" "#lang sicp (define (inc x) (+ x 1)) (define (dec x) (- x 1))"' 
had status 1 ## open-input-file: cannot open input file ## path: D:\hugo\content\sicp\#lang sicp ## (define (inc x) (+ x 1)) ## (define (dec x) (- x 1)) 
## system error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.; errid=123
```

Comment: Are you sure you were using `Racket` instead of `racket` in the chunk header as the engine name? @tjorchrt The language engines are extensible, which is exactly what the OP did: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-engine.html

Comment: Thanks, Yihui, I tried both "Racket" and "racket", neither of them works.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem by clicking the Knit button in RStudio or calling `rmarkdown::render()`. How exactly did you compile the document?

Comment: It seems when I reboot rstudio this error disappeared. Instead there is another error: 
  Warning in system2("Racket", shQuote(code), stdout = TRUE) :
  running command '"Racket" "#lang sicp
(define (inc x) (+ x 1))
(define (dec x) (- x 1))"' had status 1
## open-input-file: cannot open input file
##   path: D:\hugo\content\sicp\#lang sicp
## (define (inc x) (+ x 1))
## (define (dec x) (- x 1))
##   system error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.; errid=123

Comment: If you run into new problems, please edit your original post to provide the relevant info. The text in comments is not very readable since you can't format it. Thanks! BTW, `engine.path='~/Racket/Racket'` won't work because your engine function didn't take the chunk option `engine.path` into consideration.

Comment: I added the Racket.exe folder into the Environment Variables "Path". I can run it in the terminal by typing: "Racket".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Racket, but I guess `system2('Racket', shQuote(code))` is not the correct way to execute `code`. Typically there is a flag before the code. For example, to call R code, you call `R -e code`; for Bash code, you call `bash -c code`. I don't know what the flag is for Racket. Once you figure it out, change the `system2()` call to, say,

```r
system2('Racket', c('-e', shQuote(code)))
```

Without this flag, it is probably looking for a file input. If Racket doesn't have such a flag, you have to write the code to a (temp) file and execute it, e.g.,

```r
knitr::knit_engines$set(Racket = function(options) {
  code <- tempfile(); on.exit(file.remove(code), add = TRUE)
  xfun::write_utf8(options$code, code)
  out  <- system2(
    'Racket', shQuote(code), stdout = TRUE
  )
  knitr::engine_output(options, code, out)
})
```

Comment: Yes, Yihui, I tried the "-e" flag, it just works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the "-e" flag, it works!

```
knitr::knit_engines$set(Racket = function(options) {
  code <- paste(options$code, collapse = '\n')
  out  <- system2(
    'Racket',  c('-e', shQuote(code)), stdout = TRUE
  )
  knitr::engine_output(options, code, out)
})
```

```
{Racket, engine.path='C:/Racket/Racket', stdout=TRUE}

(define (inc x) (+ x 1))
(define (dec x) (- x 1))
(inc 5)
```

### 6